# Reordering partitions (swap) on SSD

Tags: partitioning, swap

I have dual boot (win+ubuntu 20.04) installed, order of partitions is:

1. EFI system
2. Microsoft reserved partition
3. Windows ntfs
4. nfts (hidden)
5. ubuntu / 40GB
6. swap 20gb
7. /home
8. unused 200gb

I want to extend partition 5), and to simplify operation as much as possible, i was thinking about extending it by adding 6) swap 20gb to it, and create new swap from unused space at 8)

so order would be:
1-4 the same
5. ubuntu 60gb (5+6 previoussly)
6. /home
7. swap
8. unused

Disk is ssd. I guess that order of partitions is not really important, right?

Comment: Swap partitions are generally not required anymore unless you're using ZFS. You can likely ditch partition 6, use a swap*file* instead, and expand the 40GB partition to fill the space that was once used for swap.

Comment: Be sure to comment out with #, the swap line in fstab. After you create new swap change UUID and uncomment it. Most suggest if using partition just over 4GB is fine. Default swap file is 2GB on new installs. Very large swap only required for hibernation and hibernation on recommended.